# delete a string w/ certain tags using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

i have this string

```
$output=' i want to &lt;a class=&quot;SForm&quot; onclick=&quot;ShowFormComment()&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://vnexpress.net/Images/Y-kien-cua-ban.gif&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; style=&quot;cursor:pointer&quot; alt=&quot;Ý kiến của bạn&quot; /&gt; kiss you so much';
```

and i want to get

```
' i want to kiss you so much'
```

so i tried

```
$output =preg_replace('/&lt;a class=&quot;SForm&quot; class=(.*?)\Ý kiến của bạn&quot; /&gt;/', '', $output);
```

but it didnt work

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '&' in /Users/datlap/Desktop/str.php on line 10
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work escape the `/` before `&`.

```
$output =preg_replace('/&lt;a class=&quot;SForm&quot; class=(.*?)\Ý kiến của bạn&quot; \/&gt;/', '', $output);
                                                                                       ^
```

You are using `/` as the regex delimiter and there is a unescaped `/` in the regex which is being treated as the end delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expressions for something like that...

A much simpler solution would be to use

```
$output = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($output));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Ginormous built-in function library to the rescue!